# Generate String Combinations

Tags: c#, strings, array

I have created an algorithm that can generate all possible combinations of a string given its length, and character set (it uses a custom numeral system to do this). How could I improve its performance and readability?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        Bruteforce brute = new Bruteforce(9, new Range(0, Helpers.Chars.Length - 1));
        brute.PrintResults();

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}

public class Bruteforce
{
    private int _Length;
    private Range _Range;

    public int Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _Length;
        }
    }

    public Range Range
    {
        get
        {
            return _Range;
        }
    }

    public Bruteforce(int length, Range range)
    {
        _Length = length;
        _Range = range;
    }

    public Bruteforce(int length, int min, int max)
    {
        _Length = length;
        _Range = new Range(min, max);
    }


    public void PrintResults()
    {
        int num = this.Range.Max;
        int[] arr = new int[this.Length];
        for (int c = 0; c < arr.Length; c++) arr[c] = this.Range.Min;
        while (true)
        {
            arr[0]++;
            if (arr[0] > this.Range.Max)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (arr[i - 1] > this.Range.Max)
                    {
                        arr[i - 1] = this.Range.Min;
                        arr[i]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            int num2 = arr[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++) num2 += arr[i];

            Console.WriteLine(Helpers.ArrayToString(arr));

            if (num2 == this.Range.Max * arr.Length) break;
        }
    }

    private void PrintArray(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == arr.Length - 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Helpers
{
    public static char[] Chars = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    public static string ArrayToString(int[] arr)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] >= 0)
            {
                builder.Append(Helpers.Chars[arr[i]]);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}

public class Range
{
    private int _Max, _Min;

    public int Max
    {
        get
        {
            return _Max;
        }
    }

    public int Min
    {
        get
        {
            return _Min;
        }
    }

    public Range(int min, int max)
    {
        _Max = max;
        _Min = min;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would call the permutation.    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination  The has go to be a better way to know you are done than sum the entire array.

Comment: You can mark an answer when ever you want but 1 hour is not much time for feedback.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stackexchange, I am still learning how to do things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`string.Join(string, IEnumerable<T>)`**

Your method `ArrayToString` can be replaced with a single line :

```
public static string ArrayToString(int[] arr)
{
    return string.Join("", arr.Select(x => Chars[x]));
}
```

Your method `PrintArray` is never used but I assume it's just there for testing purpose.

### Code style

**Auto properties**

You can use auto-properties to avoid explicitly creating a backing field for your variables :

> ```
> private int _Length;
>
> public int Length
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return _Length;
>     }
> }
> ```

Can be simplified to a single property :

```
public int Length { get; }
```

You can do the same for all of your properties.

**Redundant `this` qualifier**

You don't have to write `this.` everywhere e.g `this.Range.Max` as there are no variables with the same names there, the compiler will guess that you are referring to the container class.

Comment: I like your first suggestion, I never thought about string.Join. That would also get rid of that System.Text using statement. (I like programs that only have a single using statement).

Comment: Also, I use the this qualifier because it's just my style.

Comment: I agree with that `this` can be considered a personal preference it doesn't have any impact on performance but it also adds few characters of code to read.

Comment: (Sorry, I keep pressing enter for a new line, but it posts the comment instead) How will I assign the value to the auto property? Will the compiler generate the _Length field for me? And yes, the PrintArray method is for debugging stuff. I just forgot to omit that in the code I posted. Aside from that though, is there any way to improve the algorithm's performance?

Comment: @DD314 Yes auto properties still work with a backing field but it's just hidden so that it shortens your code. In your constructor for example you would simply have `Length = length;` where `Length` is your property and `length` is the parameter.

Comment: Oh ok. I wanted the properties to be readonly. However, the compiler (I am using C# 5) will error out if I don't put a set accessor as well as the get. Thus, it makes the property changeable.

Comment: Your properties are not readonly.

Comment: Also, I tried using the string.Join method, and it only returned the numbers themselves, not the letters. I was using this method to take the raw data in the array, and convert it to the characters I need. It works by Looping through all the elements in the array and append the character that is at the index specified by the current value of the spot I am at in my array.

Comment: I've edited the answer as I didn't notice those were indexes not the actual characters to convert into string. Try it out now.

Comment: For example, if I ran this method with an array that had 0, 0, 0, 1, it will return Chars[0], Chars[0], Chars[1]. In other words, it would return the string "aab". It converts it all to a string by using the StringBuilder.Append method.

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: Ah, that works better. I replaced the "" with String.Empty instead. I once read that it would be wiser to use String.Empty instead of empty quotes. I think it has to do with the fact that you save space and time at the MSIL level. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50969/discussion-between-dd314-and-denis).

Answer (score 4):

## Generating indexes

There is this principle that says that a class should have only a single responsibility. We call it the Single responsibility principle.

This means, that all the `Bruteforce` class should do, is to generate the indexes and not render the strings or write them to the console.

Apart from removing the print methods from it, there are few other things you can improve becuase the current `while/if/for/if/` implementation is really complex. There's also a bug here `arr[0]++;` where you increase the first index so the resulting array skips one item - the first one so let's fix the `PrintResults` method.

---

> ```
> for (int c = 0; c < arr.Length; c++) arr[c] = this.Range.Min;
> ```

If you like LINQ you can rewrite this loop as

```
var slots = Enumerable.Repeat(Range.Min, Length).ToArray();
```

but keep in mind that in some critical situations a peformance hit might be noticeable. However usualy you just want to use some convenience functions to get the work done.

---

The next part that needs to be simplified is this

> ```
> while (true)
> {
>     arr[0]++;
>     if (arr[0] > this.Range.Max)
>     {
>         for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
>         {
>             if (arr[i - 1] > this.Range.Max)
>             {
>                 arr[i - 1] = this.Range.Min;
>                 arr[i]++;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     int num2 = arr[0];
>     for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++) num2 += arr[i];
>
>     Console.WriteLine(Helpers.ArrayToString(arr));
>
>     if (num2 == this.Range.Max * arr.Length) break;
> }
> ```

There are particularly two things going on: increase the index and keep increasing it until all indexes are equal `Range.Max`. These two parts can be implemented separately.

```
var increase = new Func<bool>(() =>
{
    var currentSlot = 0;
    do
    {
        if (slots[currentSlot]++ < Range.Max)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // current slot exceeded
        else
        {
            // reset current slot
            slots[currentSlot++] = Range.Min;
        }
        // is last slot still less then Range.Max? if not then stop.
    } while (slots[Length - 1] <= Range.Max && currentSlot < Length);
    return false;
});
```

I let a local function take care of the indexes. It returns `true` if an index could be successfuly increased and `false` if not, this means we're finished.

The second part is quite small and just keeps this function running as long as necessary:

```
do
{
    action(slots);
} while (increase());
```

But what is `action`? This is the new delegate that is passed by the caller. He'll recive each index array via this parameter so the new signature is:

```
public void ForEach(Action<int[]> action)
```

Everything put together looks like this:

```
public void ForEach(Action<int[]> action)
{
    var slots = Enumerable.Repeat(Range.Min, Length).ToArray();

    var increase = new Func<bool>(() =>
    {
        // always start with the first slot
        var currentSlot = 0;
        do
        {
            // increase the current slot
            if (slots[currentSlot]++ < Range.Max)
            {
                return true;
            }
            // current slot exceeded
            else
            {
                // reset current slot and continue with the next one
                slots[currentSlot++] = Range.Min;
            }
        // is last slot still less then Range.Max? if not then stop.
        } while (slots[Length - 1] <= Range.Max && currentSlot < Length);
        return false;
    });

    do
    {
        action(slots);
    } while (increase());
}
```

---

Now that this method no longer prints the results I also no longer depends on the `Helpers` class..

> ```
> Console.WriteLine(Helpers.ArrayToString(arr));
> ```

---

To use it, you call the `ForEach` with an anonymous delegate or you can pass a function that has the same signature as the delegate, this is `void Foo(int[])`

```
var brute = new Bruteforce(3, new Range(0, 2));
brute.ForEach(indexes =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(Helpers.ArrayToString(indexes));
});
```

---

## More tips

> ```
> public Bruteforce(int length, Range range)
> {
>     _Length = length;
>     _Range = range;
> }
>
> public Bruteforce(int length, int min, int max)
> {
>     _Length = length;
>     _Range = new Range(min, max);
> }
> ```

Both these constructors do the same thing and initalize the same variables. You can chain them with `:this(..)` so that you don't repeat yourself:

```
public Bruteforce(int length, Range range)
{
    Length = length;
    Range = range;
}

public Bruteforce(int length, int min, int max)
: this(length, new Range(min, max))
{
}
```

---

> ```
> public static string ArrayToString(int[] arr)
> {
>   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
>   for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
>   {
>       if (arr[i] >= 0)
>       {
>           builder.Append(Helpers.Chars[arr[i]]);
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           throw new Exception();
>       }
>   }
>   return builder.ToString();
> }
> ```

Here is actually no room for exceptions. If you run into one, then something is wrong with the conditions.

> ```
> throw new Exception();
> ```

But if you throw exceptions, be so nice and try to communicate what happened, if possible why and if possible how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I typically try to stay away from LINQ because I just can't understand it (It totally violates conventional programming methods for me). I have never heard about the Single responsibility principle, I will remember that for future reference. Something to note is that I am trying to go for performance. Any speed improvements are welcome. Thanks for your feed back!